# How to access any file or sub-directory of a directory?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a root directory with a path defined as

```
string MyPath = @"D:/Documents/Reonance Tunneling";
```

I have a delete method that will delete any selected sub-directory written as follows:

```
private void BntDeleteFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode newSelected = TreeView1.SelectedNode;
        string DirectoryName = newSelected.Text;
        DirectoryInfo nodeDirInfo = (DirectoryInfo)newSelected.Tag;

        try
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete Folder " + "'" + DirectoryName + "'" + " ?", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo file in nodeDirInfo.GetFiles())
                {
                    File.Delete(MyPath + "//" + DirectoryName + "//" + item.Text);
                 }                  

                Directory.Delete(MyPath + "//" + DirectoryName + "//");
                newSelected.Remove();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

However if I try to delete any selected sub-directory of the sub-directory I get the following error: "Could not find part of the path... " or "The directory is not empty." Can anybody tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: Why are you casting a string as a string?

Comment: Why do you make a ListViewItem in your loop?

Comment: Try with: ´string MyPath = @"c:\Documents\Reonance Tunneling";´

Comment: Rather than concat bits of string consider `Path.Combine()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are recreating plenty of ListViewItems that are never used (as Scott Chamberlain pointed out).

You already have a `FileInfo` instance. Simply use: [FileInfo.Delete Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.delete(v=vs.110).aspx) on `file`.

and when you are done use `nodeDirInfo.Delete()` as well. You should probably also check for Subdirectories, not only files.

If you insist on using the static `Directory` - class, use `Directory.Delete(nodeDirInfo.Fullname, recursive: true);`

Answer (score 3):

nodeDirInfo can delete all it files and directories (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c66e2tts(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 nodeDirInfo.Delete(true);
```

Comment: nice one, didnt know it was able to recurse as well +1

Comment: Thanks! Although not answer I was looking for, adding true helps me!

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the documentation for the [`DirectoryInfo.Delete Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c66e2tts(v=vs.110).aspx), you'll notice that it takes a `bool` that defines if it should also delete the subdirectories and all files in the directory. This is probably the easiest way to get around the "The directory is not empty" exception.

To avoid the "Directory not found" exception, you can just check for it first:

```
var fullPath = Path.Combine(MyPath, newSelected.Tag);

if (Directory.Exists(fullPath))
{
    new DirectoryInfo(fullPath).Delete(true);
}
```